ADF Portal warns JSON function as parameter to XML function
The ADF portal warns when using the JSON function inside a XML function inside the dynamic content editor when setting a variable.  The XML function complains about having a string argument despite the documentation stating that a JSON object is valid.


@string(
  xml(json(
      concat(
        '{"value": ',
        activity('Get Blob Metadata').output
         ['ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders']['X-Ratelimit-Remaining'],
        '}'
      )
    )
  )
)

While using above expression in expression, you will get below error:

The above error indicates that you're trying to pass a complex object (e.g., JSON or array) to a function that expects a simple string. But it won't affect your pipeline result, debug the pipeline by clicking debug button, the expression will give exact output as required without any error as shown below:


Goes against the documentation where a XML function can expect both a string representing JSON or JSON object.  Strings representing JSON fail.
